# Save & Load QListItems when I'm running my program.

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qlistwidget

I'm new to Python and coding in general, this is actually my first project so far.
I created a GUI in PYQT and converted it to Py. 
The following code creates the page in the image below;

```
self.ListView_InsertCoin = QtGui.QListWidget(self.page_EditMarket)
    self.ListView_InsertCoin.setGeometry(300,250,220,150)
    self.ListView_InsertCoin.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: white"))
    self.ListView_InsertCoin.clicked.connect(self.Action_SelectCoinFromList)
    self.ListView_InsertCoin.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_EditMarket)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(7)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setFont(font)
    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setGeometry(420,190,100,25)
    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setStyleSheet('Background-color: white')
    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setText('Add Coin')
    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setEnabled(False)
    self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.clicked.connect(self.Action_PushButton_AddCoin)

    self.Lineedit_InsertCoin = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.page_EditMarket)
    self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.setGeometry(300,190,110,25)
    self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: white"))
    self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.setPlaceholderText('Insert Symbol')
    self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.textEdited.connect(self.Action_LineEdit_TextEdit)


    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_EditMarket)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(7)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setFont(font)
    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setGeometry(420,220,100,25)
    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setStyleSheet('Background-color: white')
    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setText('Delete Coin')
    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setEnabled(False)
    self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.clicked.connect(self.Action_PushButton_DeleteCoin)

    self.Label_DeleteCoin = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_EditMarket)
    self.Label_DeleteCoin.setText('Select to Delete')
    self.Label_DeleteCoin.setGeometry(300,220,110,25)
    self.Label_DeleteCoin.setStyleSheet('background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); \n Color: White')


    self.Pushbutton_SaveList = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_EditMarket)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(7)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setFont(font)
    self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setGeometry(300,410,220,30)
    self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0.506, y1:1, x2:0.499591, y2:0, stop:0.00568182 rgba(124, 143, 153, 255), stop:0.238636 rgba(103, 138, 158, 255), stop:0.931818 rgba(133, 131, 153, 232), stop:1 rgba(99, 111, 131, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setText('Save my List')
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('./Icons/Icon_ExitProgram.png'))
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.clicked.connect(self.Action_PushButton_SaveMyList)
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setEnabled(False)
```

---

```
def Action_SelectCoinFromList(self):
        self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0.506, y1:1, x2:0.499591, y2:0, stop:0.00568182 rgba(124, 143, 153, 255), stop:0.238636 rgba(103, 138, 158, 255), stop:0.931818 rgba(133, 131, 153, 232), stop:1 rgba(99, 111, 131, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setEnabled(True)
        self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.clear()
        self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setEnabled(False)
        self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setStyleSheet("Background-color: white")

    def Action_LineEdit_TextEdit(self):
        self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0.506, y1:1, x2:0.499591, y2:0, stop:0.00568182 rgba(124, 143, 153, 255), stop:0.238636 rgba(103, 138, 158, 255), stop:0.931818 rgba(133, 131, 153, 232), stop:1 rgba(99, 111, 131, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setEnabled(True)
        self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setEnabled(False)
        self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setStyleSheet("Background-color: white")

    def Action_PushButton_AddCoin(self):
        UserInput = unicode(self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.text())
        self.ListView_InsertCoin.addItem(UserInput)
        self.Lineedit_InsertCoin.clear()
        self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setStyleSheet('Background-color: White')
        self.Pushbutton_AddCoin.setEnabled(False)
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setEnabled(True)
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0.506, y1:1, x2:0.499591, y2:0, stop:0.00568182 rgba(124, 143, 153, 255), stop:0.238636 rgba(103, 138, 158, 255), stop:0.931818 rgba(133, 131, 153, 232), stop:1 rgba(99, 111, 131, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setEnabled(True)
        self.ListView_InsertCoin.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

    def Action_PushButton_DeleteCoin(self):
        User_Selection = self.ListView_InsertCoin.takeItem(self.ListView_InsertCoin.currentRow())
        User_Selection = None
        self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setStyleSheet('background-color: white')
        self.Pushbutton_DeleteCoin.setEnabled(False)
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0.506, y1:1, x2:0.499591, y2:0, stop:0.00568182 rgba(124, 143, 153, 255), stop:0.238636 rgba(103, 138, 158, 255), stop:0.931818 rgba(133, 131, 153, 232), stop:1 rgba(99, 111, 131, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setEnabled(True)
        self.ListView_InsertCoin.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

    def Action_PushButton_SaveMyList(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.Pushbutton_SaveList.setEnabled(False)
```

---

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCHbg.jpg)

I can Add & Delete entries from the Qlistwidget using the buttons.

**The QlistItems will eventually be used as strings to call API's with.**

Instead of adding new items to the list everytime I run my program, I want to be able to save my QListItems using 'Pushbutton_SaveList'. I also want these saved items to load automaticly once I run my program.

I checked the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870081/how-to-save-and-load-qlistwidjet-contents-to-from-qsetting-with-pyqt4) but I cant make any sense of it. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own storage list menu file in some way to save & load it. If application started, You will load list menu file in to your `QListWidget`. And, If application has exit or quit, You will save your list date of `QListWidget` in to file.

OK, I have example, I Hope this help;

```
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

FILENAME = 'listMenu.txt'

class AppQWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(AppQWidget, self).__init__()
        self.allQVBoxLayout    = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.myQListWidget     = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.addQPushButton    = QtGui.QPushButton('ADD', self)
        self.deleteQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('DELETE', self)
        self.allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQListWidget)
        self.allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.addQPushButton)
        self.allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.deleteQPushButton)
        self.setLayout(self.allQVBoxLayout)
        self.connect(self.addQPushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('released()'), self.addListMenu)
        self.connect(self.deleteQPushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('released()'), self.deleteListMenu)
        self.loadMenu()

    def addListMenu (self, menu = None):
        if menu == None:
            menu = 'MENU : ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
        self.myQListWidget.addItem(menu)
        self.myQListWidget.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

    def deleteListMenu (self):
        currentRow = self.myQListWidget.currentRow()
        if currentRow >= 0:
            self.myQListWidget.takeItem(currentRow)
            self.myQListWidget.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

    def closeEvent (self, eventQCloseEvent):
        self.saveMenu()
        eventQCloseEvent.accept()

    def loadMenu (self):
        configFile = open(FILENAME, 'r')
        allLine = configFile.readlines()
        configFile.close()
        for currentLine in allLine:
            self.addListMenu(currentLine[:-1])

    def saveMenu (self):
        configFile = open(FILENAME, 'w')
        allRow = self.myQListWidget.count()
        for row in range(allRow):
            menu = str(self.myQListWidget.item(row).text())
            configFile.write(menu + '\n')
        configFile.close()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = AppQWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**QListWidget Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html

---

Regards,

Comment: This is awesome. I'll work with this and see if I can build from here. Thank you very much for your time.